# Using a Facebook user as a Wordpress user

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I referer to [this code](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-use-facebook-user-as-wordpress-user?replies=1) which I'm trying to use to log a facebook user as a wordpress user. However the while the user is registered the is_user_logged_in() would repeatedly state false. Can anyone give me some insight as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: have you checked that WP auth cookies are present after programmatically login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a wordpress loginas.php page, hence, a really big security hole :) :

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');

function auto_login( $username ) {
    // log in automatically
    $user = get_userdatabylogin( $username );
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
}

if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo "Logging in as: ".$_GET['username'];
    auto_login($_GET['username']);
}
else
    echo "You are already logged in.";
```

And, after **I delete all cookies**, it is working very well. So, I suppose you could have a problem with something that is executed before your code.
Actually I'm still unable to figure out what's happening in your code, could you try to change priority of execution of your `init` hook and move at very first position.

Please pay attention, in order to execute your correctly your programmatically authentication,  WordPress requests should be always done on same domain where the cookie is created.

Comment: Well I had since adjusted the code and used wp_signon() which is the replacement for wp_login.....No success

Comment: Please check if you have WP auth cookie after your programmatically login.

Comment: Well I'm seeing the cookies in the debugging however why would "is_user_logged_in" still fail?

Comment: what cookies are you seeing? Please remove all cookies and try your programmatically login again. You should see three cookies: wordpress_...

Comment: Yes I am seeing the cookie **wordpress_logged_in...** but every time i try to go to another page the process runs over due to is_user_logged_in = false... could it be that i'm checking in the wrong place? i'm executing the action after "wp_loaded" instead of "init" now

Comment: are you able to log the php execution during your debug?

Comment: I had seen this snippet before...the only thing I haven't done is use the ob_start and end but the problem here is that the code I'm using keeps executing based on the condition that `if(!user_logged_in)` is returning false. which goes through the process of re-authorizing the facebook user even though this had been previously done. the wordpress is being loaded into a canvas page with SSL

Comment: could it be that I am calling the is_user_logged_in function before th e user can be instantiated on page reload?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20514/discussion-between-freedev-and-kendall)

Comment: Could we switch on the chat in order to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you give this plugin a shot http://ottopress.com/wordpress-plugins/simple-facebook-connect/

Ive used this and it works! It has a feature that would let a user to login into your site using their fb account.

Comment: Yeah i was trying it but couldn't figure how to use it with php on load of the page...

Answer (score 0):

Please try This,

First you have to create a new application in facebook. Here you have enter the your domain name of site and get the below two value.

1) Application ID

2) Secrate ID

And put below code within your function `connect_to_facebook()`:

```
define('APP_ID', 'Copy Facebook Application ID'); 
define('APP_SECRET', 'Copy Facebook Secrate ID');
```

Comment: :-/ the problem is not the Facebook user...the problem is the login of the facebook user as a wordpress user AFTER i've successfully authorized and authenticated the facebook user.

Comment: yes, I know but you have not created any application in Facebook. So Facebook cookie is not set user is not login to wordpress.

Comment: you are INCORRECT! the facebook application has been created otherwise I would NOT have gotten a Facebook User reference. I'm using PHP by the way